# Flutter Flame collisions do not update

Tags: flame

I have a simple RectangleHitbox (sort of wall) and CircleHitbox (player). When they collide each other I can see through the "onCollision" method which points are involved. However if I move the player away the method keeps on get called (printing out the same points) and if I collide again the player to the wall, still the same points from the first collision are returned. I was expecting that as soon as the player moved away from the wall the "onCollision" method was stopped to get called and display new collision points on a new collision.

```
class Player extends PositionComponent with  CollisionCallbacks, HasGameRef<MainGame> {
  Offset direction = Offset.zero;

  bool isCollided = false;

  Vector2 playerStartPosition;

  Player(this.playerStartPosition): super(
        position: playerStartPosition,
        anchor: Anchor.topLeft
    );

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    // super.onLoad();
    add(CircleHitbox(radius: 2)
      ..paint = BasicPalette.yellow.paint()
      ..renderShape = true
    );
    super.onLoad();
  }

  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
    print('Collision ON');
    print(intersectionPoints);
    if (other is Level && !isCollided) {
      isCollided = true;
      game.increaseScore();
    }
  }

  @override
  void onCollisionStart(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    super.onCollisionStart(intersectionPoints, other);
    print('Collision START');
    isCollided = true;
    if (other is Level) {
      game.increaseScore();
    }
  }

  @override
  void onCollisionEnd(PositionComponent other) {
    super.onCollisionEnd(other);
    print('Collision END');
    isCollided = false;
    // if (other is Level) {
    //   game.increaseScore();
    // }
  }

  @override
  void update(double delta) {
    super.update(delta);
    if (!isCollided) {
      position.add(direction.toVector2());
    }
  }
}

class Level extends PositionComponent with CollisionCallbacks {

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    // super.onLoad();
    add(RectangleHitbox(
        position: Vector2(80.0, 10.0), size: Vector2(2.0, 250.0), angle:0,
        collisionType: CollisionType.passive
    )
      ..paint = BasicPalette.blue.paint()
      ..renderShape = true);
    super.onLoad();
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried printing the `intersectionPoints` in the [Circles demo](https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/Collision%20Detection_Circles) and it works just like intended, the list of points update meanwhile the circles move through each other.

This was the only addition I did to that example:

```dart
  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
    print(intersectionPoints);
  }
```

I can see in your code that you have a variable that sets `isCollided` to `true` when you start colliding with anything and in your player's `update` method you say that the player should not move if `isCollided` is true, so maybe that is why you are getting the same intersection points? It's hard to say, because the part of the code that controls movement is not included.

Comment: I discovered that in Flame there is already a variable  "isColliding" that makes it unnecessary "isCollided".